# cakephp 3 fixture block to insert data

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, fixtures

I use many database view (which read from tables) in my application and these has models, too. When I run unit test, cakephp wants to build my view from the fixture, but of course, it can't insert data to it.

I would like, that unit test makes nothing with my view table, no create the table and no insert records.
How can I setting my fixture for it?

Now my fixture is empty, only connection is in it, but this way it search records (but don't want to create table):

```
class PlayersFixture extends TestFixture
{
    public $connection = 'test_main';

}
```

I tried to import settings, like this:

```
public $import = array('table' => 'players', 'records' => false, 'connection' => 'test_main');
```

But this way it want to create fixture, too.

I tried also this:

```
public $records = false;
```

but it also try to insert data.

Comment: The default fixtures sole purpose is to create tables and to insert records. So, how about not using a fixture at all, if you don't want it to do anything, and your view already exists, then you don't seem to need a fixture.

Comment: I need to read only the ready fixture, and no modify it at all.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your statement, as I don't really understand what you are trying to say. You can read data that has been created by a fixture, but you said that you don't want to create anything, so my conclusion based on that information is that you don't need a fixture.

Comment: I understand now!
I imaged that fixtures are like the models in the application. But as I see now, fixture only create and insert, and the data reading is from models. So I need just that fixtures which must create or insert.
Thanks a lot!!